# How to get C# Console Application Exit Event in WinCE 6.0?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

How to use SetConsoleCtrlHandler of coredll.dll in compact framework wince 6.0 to fetch event of closing console application using C#. I require this because when I try to run my application on WinCe 6.0 where it makes use of the serial port, the application gets stuck and there is no response from the serial port. The only way to start again is to reset the device. I have tried using ReadTimeOut as well as WriteTimeOut but still the application gets stuck this happens after the application runs for 12-13 hours.

Comment: Are you starting a console app from a winform application? If so, you can get the exitcode of the Process your code has started.